# Can't get the output in a customized manner from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script in python in combination with BeautiflSoup using selector to parse the movie names and its corresponding features from a webpage. When I execute my script, It fetches the required items partially. How can I get all the movie names and its fetaures?

I tried like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import zip_longest

with requests.Session() as session:
    r = session.get('https://yts.am/browse-movies')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    items = {item.text:itm.text for item,itm in zip(soup.select(".browse-movie-title"),soup.select("figcaption h4"))}
    print(items)
```

Results I'm having like:

```
{'Halloween H20: 20 Years Later': '5.7 / 10', 'Rabbit': 'Horror', and so on-----
```

***I suppose it's because of the `zip()` function. However, I imported `zip_longest()` which might do the trick but I could't make use of it.***

Html elements within which one such features of a single movie are:

```
<figcaption class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
<span class="icon-star"></span>
<h4 class="rating">5.7 / 10</h4>
<h4>Horror</h4>
<h4>Thriller</h4>
<span class="button-green-download2-big">View Details</span>
</figcaption>
```

This is the relevant html for a single movie:

```
<div class="browse-movie-bottom">
<a href="https://yts.am/movie/halloween-h20-20-years-later-1998" class="browse-movie-title">Halloween H20: 20 Years Later</a>
<div class="browse-movie-year">1998</div>
</div>
```

Expected output for a single movie:

```
'Halloween H20: 20 Years Later': ['5.7 / 10','Horror','Thriller']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting all elements at once. It might be hard to group. Also `zip` is not the thing you are looking for. Simply iterate through cards.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.Session() as session:
    r = session.get('https://yts.am/browse-movies')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")  

    for movie in soup.select("div.browse-movie-wrap"):
        title = movie.select_one('a.browse-movie-title').text
        details = [detail.text for detail in movie.select('h4')]
        print((title, details))
```

Output will be,

```
('Heavy Weights', ['6.7 / 10', 'Comedy', 'Drama'])
('Get Shorty', ['6.9 / 10', 'Comedy', 'Crime'])
('Fred Claus', ['5.6 / 10', 'Comedy', 'Family'])
("Free Willy: Escape from Pirate's Cove", ['5.2 / 10'])
('Halloween: Resurrection', ['4.1 / 10', 'Comedy', 'Horror'])
('Ant-Man and the Wasp', ['7.2 / 10', 'Action', 'Adventure'])
('Rabbit', ['6.2 / 10', 'Thriller'])
('Halloween H20: 20 Years Later', ['5.7 / 10', 'Horror', 'Thriller'])
("Madeline's Madeline", ['6.9 / 10'])
('Halloween 5', ['5.2 / 10'])
('Halloween: The Curse of Michael Myers', ['4.9 / 10', 'Action', 'Horror'])
('Deck the Halls', ['4.9 / 10', 'Comedy', 'Family'])
('Halloween 4: The Return of Michael Myers', ['5.9 / 10', 'Horror', 'Thriller'])
('Dark Horse', ['6 / 10', 'Action', 'Comedy'])
('Double Whammy', ['5.7 / 10', 'Comedy', 'Crime'])
('Beyond Borders', ['6.5 / 10', 'Adventure', 'Drama'])
('Dead Man Running', ['6 / 10', 'Action', 'Crime'])
('Cougar Hunting', ['3.7 / 10', 'Comedy', 'Romance'])
('Cabin Boy', ['5.2 / 10', 'Adventure', 'Comedy'])
('Illang: The Wolf Brigade', ['5.5 / 10', 'Action', 'Sci-Fi'])
```

Comment: Okay, I can live with it. My intention was to know how we could make use of ***`zip_longest()`*** in such cases to get the aforementioned output. Thanks @Selçuk.